# How to convert Android.Resource.Color to Android.Graphics.Color

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a value of `Android.Resource.Color` like `Android.Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark`.
I want to covert it to a `Android.Graphics.Color`.
How can I do that?

Comment: there is no such class Android.Resource.Color

Comment: @pskink `Android.Resource.Color` is an enum value in Xamarin.Android representing constant integers for the [Android.R.Color class in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html). So `Android.Resource.Color` is equal to the `Anroid.R.Color` in Android. The values are constant integers.

Comment: so Resources.getColor() should probably work

Comment: Do you see my answer??!! I said same @pskink said.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Resources.GetColor` has been deprecated. Make sure you use `ContextCompat.GetColor` instead.

So

```
Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark);
```

Will become

```
int colorInt = ContextCompat.GetColor(this.Context, Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark))
```

ContextCompat returns a int so to get a Color out of it just create a new color and pass in the int.

```
Color color = new Color(colorInt);
```

Comment: this.Context not exist!

Comment: so just use this on activities. this.Context is usually used of fragments

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark);
```

**UPDATE:** 
Resources.GetColor has been deprecated. You can use from ContextCompat like below:

```
ContextCompat.GetColor(mContext, Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark);
```

Comment: Here you convert a string into `Android.Graphics.Color`. But I want to convert `Android.Resource.Color` to `Android.Graphics.Color`. `Android.Resource.Color` is a constant integer like:  `holo_orange_dark`:  17170457

Comment: I use the different enum values of Android:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

Comment: `Resources.GetColor` is now deprecated.  What do you use now?

Comment: ContextCompat.GetColor(Context, Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark);

You'll have to include Android.Support.V4

Answer (score 1):

> Try this in Xamarin also

```
int colorIntFG = ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.colorCardDaysFGAlert);

txtView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(colorIntFG));
```